# Reason for slow download speeds in scp and rsync

Tags: networking, rsync, scp, speedtest

I am trying to download some files using `scp` and `rsync` from a remote computer. The files are ~20 MB to few GB in size. Trying to download them gives me ~20-30 KBps during the day and ~5 MBps at night (location in India and remote computer in US). However, when I check my internet speed using Google or Ookla speedtest, I get good download speeds of ~8 MBps irrespective of whether it is day or night. I know for sure that there is nothing wrong with the network at the remote computer. What is the reason I am getting such slow download speeds on `scp` and `rsync` during the day, much below what Google or Ookla speedtest are showing me ? Is there a way I can get better speeds for downloading files ?

Comment: You checked the download speed of one computer, but did you check the upload speed of the other? Are both using SSDs?

Comment: You're making the very big assumption that a local speedtest -- which measures your connection to the nearest speed test server -- is also an indication of the throughput of every other hop between you and your destination. Using traceroute might help you locate where your data is getting throttled. Your best bet for solution will likley be to procure space on intermediate systems that are well connected at various times.

Comment: ISPs have a habit of prioritising traffic fom known speed test sites.